# Nifty Design view does not refresh

Tags: jmonkeyengine, nifty-gui

I am using Nifty in JME SDK to make different screens. I stuck in this problem that nifty doesn't refresh its design preview to reflect any changes in xml.

But this works:
If I close .xml and reopen it changes are refreshed.

Its impractical and annoying to close/open xml each time to view changes in design. So if anybody **know any patches or method to reflect changes in design as soon as we make changes in xml**, it would be great.